# Top 3 countries

Tags: mysql

My question is surely banal but i can't set up an sql query that allows me to make a list of top 3 countries for a sport-event summary table.
I explain me better: in a sport event i have a lot of athletes from different countries and i need to produce a summary table showing countries that won more medals.
Here is an example:

```
--------------------------------------------
|id |     name    |   activity  | country  |
--------------------------------------------
| 1 |  John       |   100m      |  USA     |
| 2 |  Andy       |   200m      |  CANADA  |
| 3 |  Frank      |   400m      |  USA     |
| 4 |  Ian        |   400m      |  GERMANY |
| 5 |  Anthony    |   100m      |  USA     |
| 6 |  Eric       |   400m      |  CANADA  |
| 7 |  Mike       |   200m      |  UK      |
| 8 |  Dave       |   200m      |  GERMANY |
| 9 |  Richard    |   100m      |  USA     |
| 10|  Max        |   100m      |  USA     |
| 11|  Randy      |   100m      |  USA     |
| 12|  Maurice    |   400m      |  CANADA  |
| 13|  Col        |   100m      |  UK      |
| 14|  Jim        |   400m      |  USA     |
| 15|  Adam       |   200m      |  BRAZIL  |
| 16|  Ricky      |   100m      |  UK      |
| 17|  Emily      |   400m      |  USA     |
| 18|  Serge      |   200m      |  UK      |
| 19|  Alex       |   400m      |  FRANCE  |
| 20|  Enamuel    |   100m      |  USA     |
--------------------------------------------
```

The summary table i wish to obtain is the following:

Top 3 countries

```
--------------------------------------
| position |    country    | medals  |
--------------------------------------
|     1    |     USA       |    9    |
|     2    |     UK        |    4    |
|     3    |     CANADA    |    3    |
--------------------------------------
```

How can build the qsl query?
Thanks in advance for your kind answer.

Mattew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the position column, this is quite easy. Just do the following

```
SELECT Country,COUNT(*) AS medals
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

There is some more complicated code for getting the "position" column out, but unless you need it, it probably isn't necessary, and you can just get those numbers using a counter on the processing code.  If you're interested, the code would be something like this.

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS Position,Country,Medals FROM
(
SELECT Country,COUNT(*) AS medals
FROM Medals
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
) AS Stats, (SELECT @rownum:=0) RowNum;
```

The above query has been tested and appears to be working as you need it to be.

Comment: He's asking how to produce a another (summary) table from the result. Piece of cake - have the SQL insert that result into a new table with an auto-increment field (position)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS top_three_countries 
   (position INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, country VARCHAR(30), medals INT);
TRUNCATE TABLE top_three_countries;
INSERT INTO top_three_countries (country, medals) 
   SELECT country, count(*) total
   FROM medal
   GROUP BY country
   ORDER BY total DESC
   LIMIT 3;
```

This will produce a summary table (top_three_countries) as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler without the rank, if you can add that in your programs' logic instead:

```
SELECT `country`, COUNT(*) total
FROM medal
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Looks like Kibbee beat me too it but for a guaranteed `GROUP BY` compatible query you can wrap the above in a `SELECT` of its own:

```
SELECT @n:=@n+1 AS rank, country, total
FROM
  (
    SELECT `country`, COUNT(*) total
    FROM medal
    GROUP BY country
    ORDER BY total DESC
    LIMIT 3
  ) t1,

(SELECT @n:=0) t2
```